# Lightning Action override not working in Google Chrome

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, chrome

i created a lightning component to override the default new action for a custom object. The component is a simple dummy with no function. It displays as expected in Safari for Mac, but absolutely nothing happens in Google Chrome (latest Version)? Any ideas of what could be wrong?
Best Regards

Comment: any update? did you log a case with SF?